# Loop Through Used Range of specific Column in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get values of all cells in a specific column and add them to a list
Here is what I have tried

```
Dim rng As Range
'here ColumnName will be like "A", "B" etc...
'and SheetName will be like "Sheet001", "Sheett002" etc...
rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName).Columns(ColumnName).UsedRange
For Each cell In rng.Cells
If Not cell.Value = "" Then
ListBox1.AddItem (cell.Value)
End If
Next
```

But I am not being able to determine how to get used range of column by its name.
The data I want to read will be like this in a separate sheet

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`UsedRange` will refer to a used range of a sheet. With the `UsedRange` you can then select the required Columns.

I have modified your code a bit. See below:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim MySht As Worksheet
    Dim MyRng As Range

    Set MySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set MyRng = MySht.UsedRange.Columns("A")

    For Each cell In MyRng.Cells

        If Not cell = "" Then
          'If your List Box is in "Sheet1"
          Sheets("Sheet1").ListBox1.AddItem (cell)
          'If your List Box is in "UserForm1"
          UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem (cell)
        End If
    Next

    'To clear ListBox1 data
'    Sheets("Sheet1").ListBox1.Clear
'    UserForm1.ListBox1.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: I have sheet name and column name, from which I have to pick data from another sheet. like i have "sheet001_A", so I have to pick values of all cells in Column "A" of "sheet001"

Comment: @AdilWaqar Using `Sheets()` you need to insert the exact name of the sheet, so for Sheet1 you wont be able to use sheet001. Is your input data "sheet001_A"?

Comment: yes the sheet name is exactly "sheet001" and values are it its A column as shown in attached image in question

Comment: `Columns` does **not** require a numerical index. `Columns("A")` or `Columns("A:C")` is quite valid.